# Sparql, how to select attributes from entity

Tags: sparql

This is probably pretty simple but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a query that selects all information about a rockband. I want to select just some of the attributes, for example the name of the band. Any help is appriciated.

And I also want the information to be in english only.

```
 SELECT * WHERE {
    wd:Q856941 ?p ?o.

    #?o wdt:P571 ?inception.
    #?o wdt:P154 ?logo 

    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
 }
```

Comment: instead of using `?p` you should just use the properties URIs you're interested in. Or what doesn't work with that? It also depends on whether you want a separate column for each property or just `p` and `o` as column. So either a) do for example `wd:Q856941 wdt:P571 ?inceptionDate .` with each property using a separate variable or b) `wd:Q856941 ?p ?o . filter(?p in (wdt:P571, wdt:P2013))`

Comment: Ebglish only is done via `filter` clauses, the name property is mostly `rdfs:label`

Comment: Perfect. Really helpful. Thanks!